# VS2015 Add unit test to source control

Tags: c#, git, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, version-control

I added a unit test to my (C#) solution in Visual Studio 2015 but those unit tests are not being saved in the source control (I'm using GIT via VisualStudio.com), so can't be downloaded / run by the other remote developers.

Can unit tests be added?  If so how? I looked online and can't find a solution other than file-->source control which doesn't exists on my system.

Comment: You mean you added a UnitTest "project" to your solution right?

Comment: right click project "add to source control", make sure on check in your files aren't being excluded, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had created the project in the wrong folder.  Now I created it as a sub folder of the project it's testing all works fine.

Comment: As you have solved your issue, you can mark your reply as the answer directly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is another way to add your unit test solution in Git remote repository (so that other remote developers can download and run), you can use git command line to realize it. Steps as below:

1. Check the untracked path or files, `git status`. Assume the unit test solution is the subfolder “UnitTestProject1” under your local repository
2. Add the subfolder to git stage area, `git add UnitTestProject1/`
3. `git commit –m ‘input your comment’`
4. `git push`

Comment: I'm a little unclear on where I should be in the project folders when I do this.  Assume the following layout:

/ProjectRoot
     /MainProject
     /MainProject.Tests (this was created by VS when adding Unit Tests)

If I am in /ProjectRoot/MainProject I can run git status and get the expected results.

If I am in /ProjectRoot/MainProject.Tests then git  status says 
fatal: Not a git respository


Presumably this is because the project hasn't been added yet.  So where should I be when running the git add ?

Comment: The folder to do this is which contains all your solutions. If '/ProjectRoot /MainProject' contains all the solutions and has a '.git hide folder', so you should base here. And then use the steps above. Hope it can help you

Comment: It looks like the .git (hidden) folder is in /MainProject and not in /ProjectRoot/MainProject.  
  
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Should the UnitTest project have been created inside  /ProjectRoot/MainProject/MainProjectTests  instead of /ProjectRoot/MainProjectTests ?

Comment: If I move the UnitTest project in to the /ProjectRoot/MainProject/UnitTest folder instead things work perfectly.    Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DaveEP, can you mark it as answer since it help you :)